# Having space in the same line in html

Tags: html

I would like to have some space between the same line.. I know there are elements such as `<br>, <p>` and others. Instead of using these, I would like to add little space between the characters...

Example Code:

```
 <strong>
   New? Register here!
</strong>
 <span>
    Register
 </span>
```

I would like to have some space between them. How can do this in HTML?

Comment: question is nt clear. what exactly you want to achieve???

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your example, you may apply some CSS rules, e.g.:

```
span {
    margin-left: 5em;
}
```

Or inline:

```
<strong>
   New? Register here!
</strong>
<span style="margin-left: 5em;">
    Register
 </span>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `&nbsp;` for a space character that will not be collapsed.

Alternatively, add a span with a certain width, e.g.

```
<span style="width:50px;display:inline-block"></span>
```

(I think the element needs to be of display type `inline-block` to respect block properties such as padding, border, margin, width etc.).

Answer (score 2):

`&nbsp;` for space character.

Wonder why you need that.

Answer (score 1):

Just add ' br/  ' before closing strong tag

Answer (score 1):

use this instead:

```
<strong>
   New?&nbsp;Register&nbsp;here!
</strong>
<span>
   Register
</span>
```